# How to save data from field

Tags: pega

I'm new using pega system and still learning about it. I have a trouble about saving the data from field to data page. What step must i do and can give me some explain ?

I'm using `pega 8.1.1`

Here is my image :

The Data Page: https://ibb.co/tZYZ0qh 
The Login Form : https://ibb.co/ZYRdY6x

In the past i was trying to give the target but it doesn't work
My Target :

```
D_LoginCredentials[Password:.Login_Credentials.Password].Password
```

Here is the image :
Target Data Page : https://ibb.co/h83mtc3

I want to save the username and password after submit so i can do authentication for user, if user was submit it do checking the password that was right or not, if new user i want to add the data to page data.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the Data Transform if you just bind the controls in the Section directly to the properties on the Data Page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read: [how do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).